# how many ways are there to save something in browser Memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser, token

how many ways are there to save json or any variable , like Token in browser Memory using javascript or jquery And What is Advantages and Disadvantages of any of them And When any of them will be delete ?

Comment: Cookies, local storage, session storage. I think that's about it.

Comment: @Barmar what about IndexedDB on chrome?

Answer (score 1):

> There are two storage localStorage and sessionStorage. Here is an example of localStorage

1. localStorage.setItem('key','value'); 
   var getval =localStorage.getItem('key')
2. sessionStorage.setItem('key','value'); 
   var sessionval = sessionStorage.getItem('key');